# Error copying cells using PasteSpecial method

Tags: excel, vbscript

```
Set objExcel = createObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\deven.kamlesh.jain\Desktop\abcd.xlsx")
iRow = objworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Usedrange.rows.Count
objworkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:C"& iRow).Copy

objExcel.visible = true
Set Obj1 = objexcel.workbooks.add()
objExcel.displayalerts = false
Obj1.saveas("Copied abcd")

Obj1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

I am trying to copy one file to another, but I get an error saying that the `PasteSpecial` method of the `Range` class failed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `PasteSpecial` fails with the observed error is because the `SaveAs` operation clears the copied data. Move the `SaveAs` after the `PasteSpecial` and move the `Copy` right before the `PasteSpecial`. I would also recommend to put general configuration properties like `Visible` or `DisplayAlerts` right after the instantiation of the application object.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
  ("C:\Users\deven.kamlesh.jain\Desktop\abcd.xlsx")
Set Obj1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

iRow = objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
objWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:C"& iRow).Copy
Obj1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Obj1.SaveAs "Copied abcd"
```